# background image position in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I want to set background image to right and top of my span because my language is right to left. it's fine in firefox but in IE, is  not.
Result in IE:
[image: Result in IE]

Result in FF:
[image]
here is my HTML code:

```
<span class="info"><?php echo $GLOBALS['artcount'] . $ArticleCount;?></span> <br />
<span class="info"><?php echo $GLOBALS['artview'] . $ArticleViews;?></span> <br />
<span class="info"><?php echo $GLOBALS['failedlog'] . $FailedLogin;?></span> <br />
<span class="info"><?php echo $GLOBALS['slogin'] . $SLogin;?></span> <br />
<span class="info"><?php echo $GLOBALS['bqncnt'] . $bannedIP;?></span> <br />
```

And css:

```
.info{
    direction:rtl;
    text-align:right;
    background: url("/images/info.png") no-repeat;/*  right top ;*/
    background-position:   right top;
    /*display:block;*/
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding-right:20px;


}
```

I know if I uncomment `display:block;`  it will be ok, but I don't want to. Sometimes I need inline span not block.

Comment: @Phil oh, I forgot that:-D, thanks. post as answer;)

Comment: Can't reproduce this problem - http://jsfiddle.net/BfDQg/. Works fine in IE9

Comment: which ie browser version u are using

Comment: @amit I'm using IE9! windows 7 ultimate. If you want, I can put all html code here.

Comment: @Phil http://jsfiddle.net/YBbej/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repeating my comment above, try `display: inline-block`.

Not sure why IE appears to be repeating the background image. Further testing shows this is apparently not a problem - http://jsfiddle.net/BfDQg/